# How to display checkbox value from a form and display into pdf php?

Tags: php

I wonder why i cant display checked box value into pdf. It will prompt the error after i run the code, the prompt message says "fail to load PDF document".

This is the generatepdf.php which i using the Dompdf

```
<?php
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
{   
//$dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
$dompdf->loadHtml('
<table border=1 align=center width=400>
<tr><td>Name : </td><td>'.$_POST['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email : </td><td>'.$_POST['email'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Age : </td><td>'.$_POST['age'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Check : </td><td>'.$_POST['check'].'</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'Vertical');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
exit(0);
?>
```

This the form file htmltopdf.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="html_div">
     <form action="generate_pdf.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
      <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
      <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Enter Country">
 //this is the checkbox value i wanted to display in pdf
      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="hello"> hello
      <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="GENERATE PDF">
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

When using pdf generation, outputting anything except the generation of the PDF document itself will corrupt the PDF document.

In your example because you are echoing `echo $check;` that means that this is trying to be added to the PDF file and corrupts it.

If you remove this and it works then you should add the result into your `$dompdf->loadHtml(` section this is the only valid location for HTML when making your PDF

Comment: thanks for giving the tips, but it is still poping out the same error "fail to load PDFDocument". I wonder is it the IF statement problem?

Comment: Take out the actual PDF loading aspect and see if any errors show up. That will show if there is an issue elsewhere first. If there are any notices or errors those need fixing first